# C++ switch statement is returning weird value

Tags: c++, switch-statement

My problem is that this function returns guess as the sum of 97 and y, instead of just the letter, as the switch statement is instructing it to. The weird thing is, when I have it just return y, it is working exactly as I would expect it to. For example, when y=4, and i have it return y, 4 is displayed. When y=4 and 'guess' is returned, 101 is displayed. Disclaimer: this is not the full code. It's really long, and I think superfluous, as the only problem I have is when this specific function returns 'guess', not even when it returns y. If all the code would be useful though, i would be happy to put it up.

```
int letterguess(int z){
char guess;
int y;

y=letters[0][z];

switch (y){
            case 0:
                guess='a';
                break;
            case 1:
                guess='b';
                break;
            case 2:
                guess='c';
                break;
            case 3:
                guess='d';
                break;
            case 4:
                guess='e';
                break;
            case 5:
                guess='f';
                break;
            case 6:
                guess='g';
                break;
            case 7:
                guess='h';
                break;
            case 8:
                guess='i';
                break;
            case 9:
                guess='j';
                break;
            case 10:
                guess='k';
                break;
            case 11:
                guess='l';
                break;
            case 12:
                guess='m';
                break;
            case 13:
                guess='n';
                break;
            case 14:
                guess='o';
                break;
            case 15:
                guess='p';
                break;
            case 16:
                guess='q';
                break;
            case 17:
                guess='r';
                break;
            case 18:
                guess='s';
                break;
            case 19:
                guess='t';
                break;
            case 20:
                guess='u';
                break;
            case 21:
                guess='v';
                break;
            case 22:
                guess='w';
                break;
            case 23:
                guess='y';
                break;
            case 24:
                guess='y';
                break;
            case 25:
                guess='z';
                break;

        }

        return guess;

}
```

I really cannot see how this possibly could get messed up like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you return `char` from function returning `int`?

Comment: `guess = static_cast<char>(y) + 'a';` replaces your switch.

Comment: @Dave: Indeed, although technically not portable.

Comment: Also, consider using some math to eliminate the switch altogether.

Comment: @H2CO3: Consider the [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) character set, for example.  At least in C, only `'0'`-`'9'` are guaranteed to have contiguous values.

Comment: @Dave Newton  I think this is what you meant:
 `y=letters[0][z]+97;`

 `return y;`


This is mostly for newbies like me who might stumble upon this question. This replaced all that code above by pretty much reversing the problem I was having earlier, and taking the int value of a and returning the char value. Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
int letterguess(int z)
```

to this:

```
char letterguess(int z)
```

Then when you output the return value you'll get the letter instead of its numerical value.

Comment: it doesn't matter how it is declared. It matters how you try to output it.

Comment: @H2CO3 this is C++, so I'm assuming he's using ostreams with the `<<` operator, in which case it matters how it's declared.  I suppose `int letter = letterguess(); std::cout << (char)letter;` would work, but it looks awkward to me.

Answer (score 11):

This is exactly what you've told it to do.  In a standard [ASCII character set](http://www.asciitable.com/), `a` has value `97`, etc.

It's not entirely clear what you're *trying* to do, though.  You've specified your function's return type as `int`, but you're setting the return value to character literals.  If you want to return a character that you can then display, I'd suggest changing the return type to `char`, and doing something like the following:

```
char c = letterguess(blah);
std::cout << c << "\n";
```

Comment: oh ok I never would have figured that out. How can I make it return just the character 'a'? edit: nevermind, figured it out. Just needed to make the function 'char' instead of 'int'. Thanks so much for your help I was really frustrated

Comment: @user1418214: You **are** returning the character `'a'`, but a character is just an integer value.  It's simply a matter of interpretation.  If you did `printf("%c\n", (char)letterguess(blah));`, you'd see a character.  If you did `printf("%d\n", letterguess(blah));`, you'd see an integer value.

Comment: @user1418214 - It is returning the character 'a'. You just need to print it as a character, not an int value.

Answer (score 1):

This makes perfect sense. Since you've declared `y` to be an integer, when you output `y`, you get an integer. Since a `char` [can be mapped](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) to in an integer, the `char`'s integer value is what is output. In this case the value of 'e' is decimal 101.